# Datagrid expander (from grouping) header

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, grouping, expander

Following [this](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1947-wpf-grouping-datagrid.aspx) tutorial I had an idea to put in the Expander Header more data.
I have 2 tables (Document 1 - * Entry).
I'm displaying the Entries grouped by Documents and I don't want some data to be repeated in the 
datagrid so I thought to place it in the expander header.

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                                                **<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Document.Number or Name2}"/>**
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            ...
```

Comment: And the one million dollar question is....?

Comment: How can I display more data in the Expander Header ?

Comment: What data?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: "I have 2 tables (Document 1 - * Entry)" . I'm displaying all the entries grouped by the documents. dgEntries.Itemssource = Xmodel.Entry; . If I put a DataGridTextColumn in my datagrid the data would repeat. So I want to put the columns with the Document information in the expander header.

Comment: !http://i.stack.imgur.com/xE18H.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<Expander.Header>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupItem}}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=groupToTitleConverter}}" />
</StackPanel> </Expander.Header>
```

Converter:

```
public class GroupToTitleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        GroupItem groupItem = value as GroupItem;
        CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup = groupItem.Content as CollectionViewGroup;
        EntryViewModel entryViewModel = collectionViewGroup.Items[0] as EntryViewModel;
        string title = string.Format("{0} - {1} {2}", entryViewModel.Id, entryViewModel.Numar, entryViewModel.Obiect);
        return title;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Taking first item from collection in group to form header title might not be the most elegant solution but it will serve the purpose.

Full code is available here: [ExpanderHeadersInDataGridGroupStyle.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5382FFFF70512D0E&id=5382FFFF70512D0E!127)